# How to 301 mod_rewrite many similar URLs at once?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have many URLs like this:

`https://www.url.com/user/shop/location/scoobydoo`

They all begin the same, but the username at the end is different. I am trying to redirect 301 them all to:

`https://www.url.com/profile-scoobydoo`

This works if I use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.url\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/user\/shop\/location\/scoobydoo$
RewriteRule .* https://www.url.com/profile-scoobydoo [R=301,L]
```

The problem is, I have several thousand users and while generating them all would work, it would completely flood the .htaccess file. Surely there must be an easier way to do this by username?

But how? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^user/shop/location/(.+)$ https://example.com/profile-$1 [L,R=301]
```

You can also use [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) directive
 for your url redirection

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/user/shop/location/(.+)$ https://example.com/profile-$1
```